# UML specify creator and owner of an object

Tags: uml

I would like to know if there is a way to model in UML (class or other diagram) which class (or maybe function) is responsible for creating another specific object?

Also, I would like to know how to specify in a class diagram, who owns an object. My first guess would be to use a composition. However, I saw on stackoverflow a discussion saying that a wall can be a composition of a room, but a chair would rather be modeled as an aggregation. But in this case, which class would be responsible for destruction of the chair? I would rather the chair to be a composition of the room, and that the room is responsible for managing the chair, although the room can survive without having the chair in it.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Search for text "ownership" in http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#association-end for UML structural aspect and see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#create for an example of UML behavioral aspect of the "creator and owner" scenarios

Answer (score 2):

As you already mention, there can be several owners or creators of an object. Therefore, there are several ways to document this feature in U.M.L.

Remember, that when a developer models a class, in a class diagram, or sequence diagram, he / she really means (an object): "When I make an instance of this class ..."

Because, your question also applies to static or class members.

(1), there can be objects that are properties or fields, of another object, represented by a class diagram:

```
......................................................
..+-------------------+........+-------------------+..
..|     <<class>>     |........|     <<class>>     |..
..|      CarClass     |........|     MotorClass    |..
..+-------------------+........+-------------------+..
..|[+]   Motor        |<*>-----|        ...        |..
..+-------------------+........+-------------------+..
......................................................
```

The subobject is created by a function of the same class, maybe a constructor, or another function, but the property indicates the main object is responsible or allocating or deallocating the subobject. In a Class Diagram, this relation is indicated by a **Composition Association**, a line between the 2 classes, with a filled diamond.

(2) Sometimes the ownership process is splitted, the subobject is created somewhere,
applied in another place, and destroyed in another way.

Usually, a function, wheter global, or part of a class, creates, and returns an object. This is, sometimes called **Ownership Transfer**.

This result is stored somewhere else, and is not explicit, who is going to destroy the object, but, the creation it does gets documented.

```
...........................................................................
..+----------------------------------------+........+-------------------+..
..|                <<class>>               |........|      <<class>>    |..
..|            MotorFactoryClass           |........|     MotorClass    |..
..+----------------------------------------+........+-------------------+..
..|[+] CreateMotor(): MotorClass           |------->|        ...        |..
..|[+] DestroyMotor(ref MotorClass AMotor) |------->|        ...        |..
..+----------------------------------------+........+-------------------+..
...........................................................................
```

This is called a **Realization Association**, as is the half of specializing an object ownership. It is modeled as an arrow between the method, that creates the subobject,
and the class of the subobject. The lines is dotted.

The main class that creates the object, it is called a **Factory**.

The similar happens, when an object it is destroyed by another class.

(3) The other half of the process occurs when the created object it is used by another method, or another object (class).

Sometimes, the object it's applied by been assigned to a property or field, of a main object, even, if that main object may not be in charge of deleting the subobject.

```
......................................................
..+-------------------+........+-------------------+..
..|     <<class>>     |........|     <<class>>     |..
..|      CarClass     |........|     MotorClass    |..
..+-------------------+........+-------------------+..
..|[+]   Motor        |< >-----|        ...        |..
..+-------------------+........+-------------------+..
......................................................
```

This is called a **Aggregation Association**, and it is similar to the **Composition Association**, but, the diamond is NOT filled. The main object, it is considered,
the temporal owner of the object, even, if it is not in changed of it's creation or destruction.

The diagrams and operations of (2) and (3), are used, complementary.

(4) In case of global functions, or variables, the modeling is quite similar.

Usually, the main program, or a library may be used similar as a class.

```
......................................................
..+-------------------+........+-------------------+..
..|    <<module>>     |........|     <<class>>     |..
..|     Program       |........|    ConsoleClass   |..
..+-------------------+........+-------------------+..
..|[+]   Console      |<*>-----|[+] scan(): void   |..
..|[+]   main: void   |........|[+] print(): void  |..
..+-------------------+........|        ...        |..
...............................+-------------------+..
......................................................
```

Note: The C# / Java **Console**, it is a very good example of a global object.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Classes and objects are actually quite distinct types of beast, and mixing them is usually not a good idea: classes are found in source code and exist up until compile-time, whereas objects are runtime entities. In other words, classes do not own objects - objects do.
It should also be remembered that UML blithely ignores most of the real-world issues involved in programming, and so there are no standardized connectors for most such concepts.

Aggregation and composition are both structural relationships with (reasonably) well-defined meanings. If what you want to say is that class A is responsible for creating instances of class B, while class C is responsible for deleting them, I'd use a named directed association.

[image]

If on the other hand you want to follow the trail of a particular object from creation to deletion, that's best done in a sequence diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add an object rectangle to a class diagram for exemplifying the objects of a class. In the first compartment of the object rectangle you specify the object's ID and its type/class separated by a colon.

When you say "who owns an object" you probably refer to the lifecycle dependencies between the object's type/class and some other class that "owns" objects of that type. UML does not define any standard way how to express such lifecycle dependencies in a class diagram. They may be added in the form of user-defined (stereotyped) dependency arrows or constraint boxes.